# Comma-separated operation in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

**Table 1**:

```
T1Id      Name    SchoolIds
------------------------------
01        A       1,2,3,4
02        B       4,20,3,1
03        C       20,30,40
04        D       30,20,10,2
```

**Table 2**:

```
T2ID        SchoolIds       Username
--------------------------------------
01          1,2,3,4         a@a.com
02          20,30,40,2      b@a.com
03          30,20,10,2      c@a.com
04          4,20,3,1        d@a.com
```

There are two pages, one is login and other is records.

When someone is logging in with `username='a@a.com'` and then goes for records, then the code should display only those rows from `Table1` which are a match with columns `SchoolIds` from Table 1.

if login with `a@a.com` the desired result would be:

```
T1Id      Name     SchoolIds
-----------------------------
01        A        1,2,3,4
02        B        4,20,3,1
04        D        30,20,10,2
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: but  now what i can do ?

Comment: Some dbms products have better support for this than others. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sql server 2017

Comment: I think you should first normalized your tables !

Comment: Try my answer, it seems big. Is any suggestion put it in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do not store items as comma separated string.

Instead, go for a new table with foreign keys attached to the parent table. That will also allow you to easily get the required data.

So my advice is to create new table and store each item as separate rows with some matching id to parent table :)

Comment: means that except this there is no solution take place

Comment: Maybe there are some, but I would definitely recommend this solution. It's quite elegant and pretty common :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems Big, But it gives what you want. Is any suggestions, kindly put in the comments.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(T1ID INT, Name VARCHAR(1), SchoolIds VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(01,'A','1,2,3,4')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(02,'B','4,20,3,1')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(03,'C','20,30,40')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(04,'D','30,20,10,2')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(T2ID INT, SchoolIds VARCHAR(20), Username VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(01,'1,2,3,4','a@a.com')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(02,'20,30,40,2','b@a.com')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(03,'30,20,10,2','c@a.com')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(04,'4,20,3,1','d@a.com')


SELECT A.T1ID,Name,
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [SchoolId]  
INTO #T1Vals
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT T1ID,Name,
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SchoolIds, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  @Table1
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);

SELECT A.T2ID,Username,
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [SchoolId]  
INTO #T2Vals
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT T2ID, Username,
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SchoolIds, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  @Table2
     WHERE Username='a@a.com'
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);

 SELECT * 
 FROM @Table1 
 WHERE T1ID IN(
    SELECT T1ID 
    FROM #T1Vals 
    WHERE [SchoolId] IN(SELECT [SchoolId] FROM #T2Vals))

 DROP TABLE #T1Vals
 DROP TABLE #T2Vals
```

Output:

```
T1ID    Name    SchoolIds
1       A       1,2,3,4
2       B       4,20,3,1
4       D       30,20,10,2
```

Comment: for the table its working but how everything doing with view?

Comment: Just replace the name of the view in the name of the tables